# error updating table field with cakephp

Tags: php, database, cakephp

i have a controller in cakephp named AdminsController. With the addadmin($id) function,as you can see,i try to update a user's role to 'admin',finding him in the database using his user id (the variable $id).

```
class AdminsController extends AppController {

public $helpers = array('Html','Form');
var $uses = array('Admin', 'User');



public function index() {
    if(!($this->Auth->user('username') && $this->Auth->user('role') == 'admin')) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Unauthorized access.Please login first.'));
        $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users','action' => 'login'));

    }
}



public function addAdmin($id) {
    $this->loadModel('User');
    $this->User->id = $id;
    $this->User->set('role','admin');
    $this->User->save();
}



}
```

But this code does not work,though many other cakephp users in stackoverflow have told me that this is the way to do this..
Do you knwo what maybe goes wrong or you can help me in any case?

thank you in advance!

Comment: You haven't provide enough info. Please post you Admin and User model (I think just the relations are fine) and maybe the database tables.

Comment: my user model:http://pastie.org/private/v4mgm2qzx0wz0th9xmsr7g
and my admin model:http://pastie.org/private/go6oysxkrs7uz5mltay8cw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function addAdmin($id) {
    $this->loadModel('User');
    $this->User->id = $id;
    $this->User->saveField('role','admin');
}
```

If that doesn't work, you are not getting the right ID.

Answer (score 1):

Is 'role' is a field in your `users` table? And is 'admin' a valid value for that field? If so this should work:

```
$this->User->id = $id;
$this->User->saveField('role', 'admin');
```

See [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-savefield-string-fieldname-string-fieldvalue-validate-false). Hope this helps.